# How can i create permanently accessible urls from database entries?

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am trying to make a mirror of the [this site](http://either.io/150886/do-u-even-liftor-leg-day) for my own country, but I am having a hard time comperehending how to create new urls from my database entries.

For example as on the site I linked, it has and id/name to identify that exacty site, i want to achieve the same to make seperate questions shareable.

My current code is only created to test with 1 question on localhost url.

Here's a little snippet of what I've currently got:

```
    <?php
    $id = 1;
    $result = performQuery("SELECT * FROM dilemmas WHERE id = ".$id);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $blue_question = utf8_encode($row['blue_question']);
        $blue_votes =  utf8_encode($row['blue_votes']);
        $red_question = utf8_encode($row['red_question']);
        $red_votes = utf8_encode($row['red_votes']);
    }
    ?>

<div class="answer-peek">
    <div class="peek-text">Vil du helst...</div>
    <div class="peek-buttons">
        <div class="peek-bluebutton"><?php echo $blue_question ?></div>
        <div class="peek-redbutton"><?php echo $red_question ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-center" id="textrow">
    <h3 style="color:white;">Vil du helst...</h3>
</div>
<div class="row" id="buttonrow">
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="button-left"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10"><
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 button" id="bluebutton">
    <div class="blueCheckDiv"></div>
        <div id="text-container">
            <table cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <div class="result">
                                <div class="percentage">
                                    <?php
                                    $percent = $blue_votes/($blue_votes + $red_votes);
                                    $percent_friendly = number_format( $percent * 100, 0 ) . '%';
                                    echo $percent_friendly;
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-votes">
                                <span class="count">
                                <?php echo $blue_votes; ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="word">
                                    enige
                                </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="question-text">
                                <?php echo $blue_question ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p class="question">
                            <?php echo $blue_question ?>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 button" id="redbutton">
    <div class="redCheckDiv"></div>
        <div id="text-container">
            <table cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <div class="result">
                                <div class="percentage">
                                    <?php
                                    $percent = $blue_votes/($blue_votes + $red_votes);
                                    $percent_friendly = number_format( $percent * 100, 2 ) . '%';
                                    echo $percent_friendly;
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-votes">
                                <span class="count">
                                    <?php echo $red_votes ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="word">
                                    uenige
                                </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="question-text">
                                    <?php echo $red_question ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p class="question">
                            <?php echo $red_question ?>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="button-right"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="dividerrow">
    <div class="col-md-8" id="divider-left"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="divider-right"></div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="socialrow">
    <div class="col-md-8 socialcol" id="col-left"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 socialcol" id="col-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sooo, what is your question?

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is more complex than how it seems. I suggest you to use a framework to start learning PHP: you'll not understand the inner dynamics, but it will give you some useful tool to make your website work. More, after some weeks (or months, depending on how much practice you'll do) you'll can go deeper and understand how it works. But using a framework will mitigate security risks and will give you line guides about how to write code and how to structure it. You can try something like Symfony (complex but very powerful), Laravel, Yii... Or search for `php framework`.

Comment: The question is in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you to use a framework in the comments to your question.

Anyway, to do what you are trying, you can try something like this:

```
<?php
$id = 1;
if (true === isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}

$result = performQuery("SELECT * FROM dilemmas WHERE id = ".$id);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $blue_question = utf8_encode($row['blue_question']);
    $blue_votes =  utf8_encode($row['blue_votes']);
    $red_question = utf8_encode($row['red_question']);
    $red_votes = utf8_encode($row['red_votes']);
}
```

And you can call this same page with something like `example.com/page.php?id=1234`.

So, you can build links for each question like this:

```
<a href="/page.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Share</a>
```

NOTE: This is a really dirty code and it opens to a lot of security issues. I wrote it only to make you able to understand the dynamics, but, again, I suggest you to use a framework on the first start: make all in "plain" PHP will cause you to deal with a lot of complex problems like the security or the handling of routing or services, etc... Use a framework to find very good guidance and to learn faster and better the language of your choice (PHP in this case).